# PSexec error trying to scan subnet

Tags: powershell, csv, for-loop, ip, psexec

Tried tons of different methods I've seen searching but keep getting the error, "The handle is invalid".

Tried running off a .txt and a .csv. Long story short we're just trying to run `ipconfig /all` on all of our servers which are on a set vlan and export it out to use. Any help is appreciated!

```
for ($a = 1; $a -le 255; $a++){
psexec \\10.9.100.$a ipconfig /all
}>C:\Scripts\serverinfo.csv
```

Comment: This code works for me with the notable exceptions that I am testing with known windows servers (.1 is typically a switch/router) and I am ignoring that psexec sends information to the error stream. Would be a good idea to use `Test-Connection` before you attempt psexec. Perhaps you are having a permissions or security issue on your target machines http://superuser.com/questions/200938/psexec-the-handle-is-invalid. Do you have the proper rights as the running user `-u -p`?

Comment: this is what things look like even when i add in -u & -p
[link](http://i.imgur.com/CGjqmBr.png)

Comment: That is actually not a problem per sei. psexec sends information to the erorr stream. Powershell is reacting to it like it is a problem.

Comment: Awesome, I'm currently running it. Just takes a wicked long time to timeout on empty IP addresses but hopefully once it's finished it will pipe out properly. 

Thanks all!